# How to stop a numerical resolution of a differential equation with a certain condition

Tags: python, numeric, resolution, differential-equations, odeint

I am trying to solve a rather complex differential equation :

[image]

I'm trying to solve it numerically with odeint function. I've succeeded in doing so, but i would like to add a condition, and to stop the resolution when dY/dt is close to 0. I have found nowhere how to do so, would you have any ideas ? Thanks !

Comment: The math module has a function `math.isclose()` which can use an absolute or relative tolerance to check against zero. Or is your problem in using such as this in your (not shown) code?

Comment: Use `solve_ivp`, where you can define events. With the method="LSODA" you can even use the same underlying algorithm.

Comment: Well, you can solve directly for Y and dY/dt. So, just solve up to time ydot(0)/(mu.g)